# cache issue - misaligned views cached output

Tags: views, caching

I am trying to set the view on the home page. 
http://www.userbase.com/

The content gets misaligned for anonymous user. I can see proper output if I am logged in.

Any ides?

I am using following cache plugins:

- Block Cache Alter
- Render cache
- Render cache for comments added to a node
- Render cache for display suite views integration
- Render cache for node_show
- Render cache for views_plugin_row_node_view
- Safe cache_form Clear

Comment: does clearing the cache have any effect?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add `clearfix` to the css attribute of your views rows.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! it worked. But I still have the missing rows. Any ideas? You can check now

Comment: You didn't say anything about missing rows. From a quick glance it looks like you need more filters on your view, maybe: content type, publish status, ?